# In Rust, what trait do I need to compare a generic to an integer

Tags: generics, rust, traits

How can I compare the result of a calculation to a generic?
T is always some unsigned integer type(u64, u32, etc), so the in the snippet should work, but how can i convince the rust-compiler?

```
fn reproduction<T>(val: T) -> bool
where
    T: PartialOrd
{
    let var_of_type_integer = 7; // actually the result of a calculation
    if val < var_of_type_integer { // ERROR: expected type parameter, found integer
        return true;
    }
    false
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) trait can take a generic parameter to specify what type it can be compared against:

```rust
pub trait PartialOrd<Rhs = Self>: PartialEq<Rhs>
where
    Rhs: ?Sized,
{
    // ...
}
```

So this compiles:

```rust
pub fn reproduction<T>(val: T) -> bool
where
    T: PartialOrd<i32>,
{
    let var_of_type_integer = 7;
    if val < var_of_type_integer {
        return true;
    }
    false
}
```

Being able to compile if of course only half of the story. When you or users actually call the function with value of some concrete type, that type has to satisfy the specified `PartialOrd<i32>` trait bound.

Comment: You beat me to it by 37 seconds! I'll delete mine - it's basically the same.

Comment: @PeterHall yeah :P

Comment: Nice! Indeed it works.
So will specifying i32 generate a 32-bit comparison and break if var_of_type_integer happens to be larger?

Comment: @weary in that case, you can change the trait bound like so: `T: PartialOrd<i64>`. Or even multiple bounds `T: PartialOrd<i32> + PartialOrd<i64>,` or more.

Comment: @weary if `var_of_type_integer` is actually larger and you only specify `PartialOrd<i32>`, it is a type error and the code won't compile. Rust will not implicitly cast the value and generate binary that breaks at runtime.